# how to sort hash in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I need to sort hash using perl.

my hash is :

```
2 nameA
5 nameB
4 nameC
2 nameD
3 nameE
```

the result should be:

```
2 nameA
2 nameD
3 nameE
4 nameC
5 nameB
```

How do that ?

Thanks,

Miko

Comment: Hashes are not inherently sortable. That's why they're hashes and not arrays. What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish? Do you just want to print out the key-value pairs of the hash sorted by key?

Comment: Also, wait a minute....`2` appears as a key twice.

Comment: As @JackManey states: a hash cannot have the same key twice, so the example you put is definitely not a Perl hash. What are your trying to do?

Comment: That is my problem. 2 appears twice, and i need to sort this information but the first key so it will be 2,2,3,4,5. That's why edem solution didn't worked.

Comment: No, it is impossible to have the same key twice, so you cannot have a hash like that. You can have *data* like that, but not a hash.

Comment: Great if no hash how to do that ?

Comment: I have no idea what kind of data structure you have. If you have that data in a file, or similar, there are ways to sort it.

Comment: ok. if not using hash can you help me how to do that in another way ?

Comment: no because the data structure can't exist, you can't have two items with the same key in an array or a hash.

Comment: What about adding new index and sort the data by other col ?

Comment: You seem confused about what kind of data you have. I have added a solution on how to sort a file, which I assumed is what you have.

Comment: What actual data do you have? Post the code that you used to grab or generate that data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort the keys and store them in an array. An array will preserve the order. I used a numerical sort here, since your keys were numerical.

```
my @sorted_keys = sort { $a <=> $b } keys %hash;
```

Now you can access them as you wish:

```
print "$_ $hash{$_}\n" for @sorted_keys;
```

You cannot, however, store the sorted result in a hash, because hashes are not ordered. And you cannot have a hash where the key `2` appears with two different values. It is impossible by design.

If you for example have that data in a file, you can do a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). (Read the comments from the bottom and up and it will make sense):

```
open my $fh, "<", $filename or die $!;
my @sorted = map $_->[2],                   # Then map them back into the third
             sort {                     
                 $a->[0] <=> $b->[0] ||     # Sort them numerically on first
                 $a->[1] cmp $b->[1]        # ..or alphabetically on second col
             } map [ split, $_ ],           # Map them into a 3-element array ref
                 <$fh>;                     # Take all the lines in the file
```

The chained statements inside the sort will take effect when two values cannot be distinguished, e.g. "2" and "2" returns 0 from the `<=>` operator. In such cases, the sort will instead be alphabetically on the second column, which we stored in array element 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (sort keys %hash) {
  print "$_ : $hash{$_} \n";
}
```

Comment: feel free to had a little textual explanations :-)